# behat features launch browser but closed immediately

Tags: javascript, selenium, behat

I encountered issue on behat features that launch the browser but closed immediately. Can you please tell me how to fix that?

```
# features/search.feature
Feature: Search
  In order to see a word definition
  As a website user
  I need to be able to search for a word

  @javascript
  Scenario: Searching for a page that does exist
    Given I am on "/wiki/Main_Page"
    When I fill in "search" with "Behavior Driven Development"
    And I press "searchButton"
    Then I should see "agile software development"

  @javascript
  Scenario: Searching for a page that does NOT exist
    Given I am on "/wiki/Main_Page"
    When I fill in "search" with "Glory Driven Development"
    And I press "searchButton"
    Then I should see "Search results"
```

Comment: Please provide the stack-trace of the exception and the method that throws it, what you currently provided does not give any info and does not help in any way to figure out what issue you might have.

Comment: Try to use the latest selenium server and the last chromedriver.